# How do I add multiple hyperlinks to a table cell from a list in the datasource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, telerik-grid, radgrid

I need to add multiple hyperlinks to the table cell in radgrid so users can click the link to redirect them to another page. The datasource of the grid is a domain which contains a list of links for each customer.

```
 public class CustomerOverviewDomain
{
    public CustomerEntity Entity { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LeadDomain> Leads { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<QualifiedLeadsDomain> QualifiedLeads { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProspectDomain> Prospects { get; set; }
    public List<string> Links
    {
        get
        {
            //NavigateUrl = '<%# "~/Reporting/SalesProposal/ProposalDownload.aspx?proposalId="+Eval("entity.ProposalId") %>' >
            List<string> Links = new List<string>();
            foreach (LeadDomain lead in Leads)
            {
                string link = "~/LeadsManagement/Leads/LeadsDetail.aspx?leadId=" + lead.entity.LeadId;
                Links.Add(link);
            }
            foreach (QualifiedLeadsDomain qlead in QualifiedLeads)
            {
                string link = "!/LeadsManagement/QualifiedLeads/QualifiedLeadDetailPage.aspx?qualifiedLeadId=" + qlead.Entity.QualifiedLeadId;
            }
            foreach (ProspectDomain prospect in Prospects)
            {
                string link = "~/Prospects/ProspectDetailPage.aspx?prospectId=" + prospect.entity.ProspectMasterId;
                Links.Add(link);
            }
            return Links;
        }
    }
}
```

I am unsure of what should be the column in the radgrid and how the data should be databound.

```
 <%--<telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Links"
                    DataField="Links" SortExpression="Links" UniqueName="Links" 
                    ShowFilterIcon="false" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" AutoPostBackOnFilter="false" FilterDelay="500">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="120px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>--%>

                <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn DataTextField="Links" DataNavigateUrlFields="Links" UniqueName="Links">
                </telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn>

                <%--  <telerik:GridTemplateColumn
                    UniqueName="Links"
                    AllowFiltering="false"
                    HeaderText="URL">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="Link" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>--%>
```

I'm guessing something has to be done in the databound event but not sure what exactly. I'm stuck here. Most I could get is a hyperlink "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" which links nowhere. Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
protected void rgCustomer_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
        {
            //Get the row from the grid.
            GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
            if (item != null)
            {
                List<string> links = item["Links"].; 
                //GridTableCell linkCell = (GridTableCell)item["Links"];

                //var Link = item["Links"];
                //if (Link != null)
                //{

                //    TableCell cell = item["Links"];
                //    if (cell != null)
                //    {

                //    }
                //}
            }
        }


       //// GridTableCell linkCell = (GridTableCell)item["TemplateLinkColumn"];
       // HyperLink reportLink = (HyperLink)reportLinkCell.FindControl("Link");

       // // Set the text to the quote number
       // reportLink.Text = "Google";

       // //Set the URL
       // reportLink.NavigateUrl = "http://www.google.com";

       // //Tell it to open in a new window
       // reportLink.Target = "_new";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you basically need is a nested Grid in a template column. The way i have dealt with this is to nest a radgrid in a template column and on the `ItemDataBound` event of the parent row, find the nested radGrid and the `DataKeyName`. I then use the datakey value to pull the data for the current row and bind the data to the nested RadGrid.

ASPX:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid3" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid3_NeedDataSource" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnItemDataBound="RadGrid3_ItemDataBound">
            <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ID">
                <Columns>
                    <%-- Other columns  --%>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Id" DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Name" DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <%-- Column with nested template --%>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="Links" HeaderText="Links">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid4" runat="server" Skin="Windows7" RenderMode="Lightweight">
                                <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Id" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeader="false">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <%-- I have included an id and name column for demo purposes. they can be removed so only the link is displayed --%>
                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id" UniqueName="Id" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter Id column"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" UniqueName="Name" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter Name column"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlFields="Link" DataTextField="Link" HeaderText="Link" SortExpression="Link" UniqueName="Link" FilterControlAltText="Filter Link column"></telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn>
                                    </Columns>
                                </MasterTableView>
                            </telerik:RadGrid>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

C#:

```
protected void RadGrid3_NeedDataSource(object sender, 
GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    //Populate parent table with temp data
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Name");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        table.Rows.Add(i, "Name" + i.ToString());
    }

RadGrid3.DataSource = table;
 }


protected void RadGrid3_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    //If its a row item
    if (e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.Item | e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.AlternatingItem) {
    dynamic item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;

    //Find the nested Radgrid in the row
    RadGrid subGrid = (RadGrid)item("Links").FindControl("RadGrid4");
    //Get the current row's datakey value
    int currentRowDataKeyValue = item.GetDataKeyValue("ID");

    //Create temp data for nested radgrid
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Name");
    table.Columns.Add("Link");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        table.Rows.Add(i, "Row " + currentRowDataKeyValue.ToString + ": Link " + i.ToString, "https://www.google.com");
    }

    //Set datasource for nested radgrid. This is where you would databind the list of strings from your domain. You will probably need to manipulate the data returned to match the nested grid structure if you want additional columns
    subGrid.DataSource = table;
    subGrid.DataBind();

}
```

Alternatively, you can add the links to the DetailTemplateColumn. This is pretty much the same solution, but it displays the nested RadGrid underneath the row instead of in a template column.

ASPX:

```html
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound1">
  <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ID">
    <Columns>
      <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Id" DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
      <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Name" DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    </Columns>
    <DetailItemTemplate>
      <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid2" runat="server" Skin="Windows7" RenderMode="Lightweight">
        <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Id" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeader="false">
          <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id" UniqueName="Id" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter Id column"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" UniqueName="Name" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter Name column"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlFields="Link" DataTextField="Link" HeaderText="Link" SortExpression="Link" UniqueName="Link" FilterControlAltText="Filter Link column"></telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn>
          </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
      </telerik:RadGrid>
    </DetailItemTemplate>
  </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

C#

```
 protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, 
GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Name");
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    table.Rows.Add(i, "Name" + i.ToString());
}

RadGrid1.DataSource = table;

}



protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound1(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.Item | e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.AlternatingItem) {
    dynamic item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;

    //Find the grid in the DetailTemplate Cell
    RadGrid subGrid = (RadGrid)item.DetailTemplateItemDataCell.FindControl("RadGrid2");
    // Get the current row datakey value
    int currentRowDataKeyValue = Convert.ToInt32(item.GetDataKeyValue("ID"));

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Name");
    table.Columns.Add("Link");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        table.Rows.Add(i, "Row " + currentRowDataKeyValue.ToString + ": Link " + i.ToString, "https://www.google.com");
    }

    subGrid.DataSource = table;
    subGrid.DataBind();

}

}
```